# Ignite: ERROR: Java classpath is empty

Tags: ignite

I installed ignite from source. Ref: https://apacheignite-cpp.readme.io/docs/getting-started-1

On executing the following command:

```
./modules/platforms/cpp/ignite/ignite
```

I get:

```
Ignite: ERROR: Java classpath is empty (did you set IGNITE_HOME environment variable?)
```

However, I have already set IGNITE_HOME using this command:

```
export IGNITE_HOME="/home/ec2-user/ignite"
```

I also tried executing :

```
./modules/platforms/cpp/ignite/ignite -igniteHome="/home/ec2-user/ignite"
```

However, I still get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is in your `/home/ec2-user/ignite` directory? Why there is no `libs` directory? `IGNITE_HOME` environmental variable should point to the directory where you have extracted your binary package. For example if you download and extract Ignite 1.5.0.final binary package then `IGNITE_HOME` should point to the root of `apache-ignite-fabric-1.5.0.final-bin` directory.

**UPDATE:**

If you are using sources distribution then you should set `IGNITE_HOME` variable to `target/release-package` that appears after you have run `mvn package`.

Comment: I had to compile the source in order to use cpp version of ignite. So there was no libs folder even when I extracted and compiled the source.

Comment: Actually, cpp version is included in binary package too. You can find it under `platforms/cpp/`.

Comment: What is equivalent path of ./modules/platforms/cpp/ignite/ignite in binary package?

Comment: When you say `./modules/platforms/cpp/ignite/ignite` do you mean binary? In binary package there is directory `platforms/cpp/ignite`. You still need to build cpp client though and binary will appear there when you do that.

Comment: Yeah I meant binary. Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have figured out the issue. It can be solved by:

```
export IGNITE_NATIVE_TEST_CLASSPATH=true
```

Issue is because it tried to search jars in

```
std::string libsPath = home + "/libs";
```

However this directory is not created. On setting the above environment variable, it recursively searches all the directories in modules/ and examples/ folder for adding jars.